Adding a control group to a 2x2 Anova
I am conducting an experiment with 2 factors in which participants will be provided feedback regarding a task. Factor 1 is valence (positive or negative), and factor 2 is feedback detail (low vs high). So each factor has 2 levels.
Additionally I would like to add a control group which will not be manipulated at all (no feedback).
The aim is to test the effect of this feedback on task persistence.
I would then like to compare feedback vs no feedback, positive vs negative feedback, and high vs low detail, and whether there is an interaction between the two factors.
So I'm confused - should this control group be considered as a factor or not? If yes, which factor will it represent? Or will it represent both factors? And then how will it be analyzed as a 3x3 Anova instead of a 2x2?
Also, I assume the decision on how to analyze the data also affects the size of the control group?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Added more detail about the problem.
